# Spark repartition dataframe cause datasize increase 10 times

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

There are 40GB gzipped tsv files stored on S3.

I load it by using

```
df = spark.read.csv()
```

and store the `df` on to the HDFS by

```
df.write.parquet()
```

The resultant size after that is 20 GB

But if I call `repartition` on the DataFrame before storing it, the data size increases about 10x

```
df.repartition(num)
df.write.parquet()
```

Event I use `repartition` and give the argument equal to the existing number of partitions, data size still increases a lot.

This makes the operation extremely slow.

But I do need the `repartition` step because the `sc.read.csv` doesn't return a reasonable partitioned DataFrame.

Anyone knows about this issue?

Comment: GZip is not a splittable codec in Hadoop. That's why you don't get a lot of partitions when you read the CSV. I don't think there's much you can do here apart from changing the type of your file or probably extracting it before you read it using Spark.

Comment: You need to review your partition size when writing in parquet ! This is quite broad to answer